# object 'Cdqrls' not found when building R packages using devtools

Tags: r, package, devtools

I got an error as the title shows

```
Error: object 'Cdqrls' not found
```

I use `devtools` for building R packages, and one function in my current package, I used

```
.Call(Cdqrls, x[, id1, drop=FALSE] * w,  w * z, epsilon)
```

and also includes a `lm.c` file in the `src` folder, which includes:

```
...
SEXP Cdqrls(SEXP x, SEXP y, SEXP tol)
{
    SEXP ans, ansnames;
    SEXP qr, coefficients, residuals, effects, pivot, qraux;
    int n, ny = 0, p, rank, nprotect = 4, pivoted = 0;
    double rtol = asReal(tol), *work;
...
```

directly copied from R source files. When I used `load_all()` in `devtools`, it compiles shared objects in src/ (I checked that works well) with new files: `lm.o` and `MyPkgName.so`. However, from the wiki of `devtools`, I found that

```
load_all ignores the package NAMESPACE
```

If working properly, I think by running some functions, I am able to **update** the `NAMESPACE` file to contain `useDynLib(MyPkgName, Cdqrls)`. Is that correct? I think in that way the error may disappear... Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

**Update**

According to @mnel and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407615/adding-usedynlib-through-roxygen) post, it seems that using `@useDynLib` should work. However, the function I used `.Call()` is NOT documented, and there are several functions that used `.Call` so I personally do not wanna document them as they're not used for end-users. Thus, where shall I put `@useDynLib`?

Comment: Are you using `roxygen` to create your package? if so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407615/adding-usedynlib-through-roxygen

Comment: @mnel: thanks! I am using roxygen2. I read the post you mentioned, and it seems that @ useDynLib is the one to use. Please see the updated post above ;-)

Comment: @mnel: BTW, shall I use @ useDynLib Cdqrls? Thanks!

Comment: More likely `@useDynLib yourpackagename`, or `@useDynLib stats` if you want to use `Cdqrls` from the stats package....

Comment: @mnel: thanks! I used @ useDynLib pkgname Cdqrls and it works now ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use `@useDynLib PkgName Routine1 Routine2` using roxygen2, so that once running `document()` function in `devtools` the NAMESPACE file will contain `useDynLib(PkgName,Routine1,Routine2)`, which will work perfectly.